# How to enable GeoLocation in StackBlitz.com?

Tags: configuration, geolocation, stackblitz

I am trying to run this app (not mine) in StackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-geolocation

But I am receiving this error in the console: `Geolocation has been disabled in this document by Feature Policy.`

I have set the StackBlitz.com site allow Location within my Chrome browser but I still receive the error.

How can I enable GeoLocation so I can run this app?